# Invalid API Key | Next.js

Tags: next.js, supabase

Hey I'm running into some issues with setting up Supabase in my Next.js application. I've been working on a web app where I need user authentication and access to a database.
I've configured Supabase clients both for server-side and client-side, and I've followed the official Supabase documentation and some online tutorials.
However, it seems like I'm making some mistake in my implementation because I constantly receive errors like "Invalid API Key" or "Either NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL and NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY env variables are required".

I've double-checked my environment variables and the Supabase configuration in my app, but still can't seem to pinpoint where the issue lies. Below are some relevant code snippets from my app

Comment: Having the same issue, but only in production. Are you having this issue in development environment? You should be able to put those in .env locally and have it work. I've entered those in my environment variables for production on Vercel and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had to explicitly pass my key and URL when creating the client for this to work in the production environment. I thought the nextjs helper would be able to resolve it automatically based on the environment variable name (as it does in local), but I guess not.

```
const supabase = createRouteHandlerClient<Database>({ cookies: () => cookieStore }, { supabaseKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY, supabaseUrl: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL})
```